# Is the principle part of a meromorphic differential independent of local parameter?

Tags: complex-analysis, differential-geometry, riemann-surfaces

Suppose we have a Riemann surface $S$, a local parameter $z$ around point $p$ and a principle part $f(z)=\sum_{i\ge -n} a_iz^i$. Then $\eta=f(z)dz$ is a meromorphic differential. We use another parameter $w$ and $\eta=f(z)dz$ becomes $\sum_{i\ge -n} b_iw^i dw$. Do we have $a_i=b_i$ for $i<0$ ? I know $a_{-1}=b_{-1}=1/2\pi i \oint \eta$

Comment: (It's princip**al** [adj.] part, to be picky.)

Comment: Compared to your previous post, this one is getting better. Because you have made this a question about the $1$-form, rather than about the function, you *now* can you conclude that $a_{-1}=b_{-1}$. The other coefficients are still not equal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. For example, consider
$$\alpha = \left( \frac{1}{z^2} + \frac{1}{z}\right) dz$$
on $\mathbb C$. With another local coordinates $z=2\omega$,

$$ \alpha =\left( \frac{1}{(2\omega)^2} + \frac{1}{2\omega}\right) d(2\omega) =  \left( \frac{1}{2\omega^2} + \frac{1}{\omega}\right) d\omega.$$